# The infinite sum of functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Can anyone give me some hints about the following problem? Many thanks!

Let $\{f_n\}_{n\ge 0}$ be a sequence of integrable functions where each $f_n: (E, \mathcal{M},\mu)\to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ such that 
$$\sum_{n\ge 0}\int_E \big|\,f_n\,\big|\,d\mu<+\infty.$$
Show that the function $\sum_{n\ge 0}f_n$ is well-defined almost everywhere on $E$ ("well-defined" in the sense that its value is either a real number or $\infty$). Is it enough to show that $\sum_{n\ge 0}f_n$ is integrable on $E$?

Comment: Yes, it is enough to show that it is integrable (in fact, that is the point of the problem)